# Валидация данных через атрибут Remote ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Прочитал в книге Палермо, что правильно создавать отдельный класс специально для представления. И что этот класс может (и так часто делается) содержать в себе как данные для отображения так и для ввода данных в отдельном, вложенном классе. Например так:

```
public class Datas
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Tovar tovars { get; set; }
    public class Tovar
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Ощибочка вышла")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("Test", "Home", ErrorMessage="Мала букафф")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Для ввода данных я использую вложенный класс `Tovar`. Но вот у меня с этим классом возникла дилема, в моем контролере есть метод действия для быстрой (удаленной) валидации данных. Вот он

```
public JsonResult Test(string Name)
{
    return Json(Name.Length > 5, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Как известно этот метод требует, чтобы имя его параметра совпадало с именем атрибута `name` в этом поле ввода. Так вот проблема заключается в том, что движок генерирует страницу с именем атрибута `tovars.name`, что не подходит под имя параметра, и переименовать параметр в это имя из-за наличия в имени . - точки невозможно. Я попытался изменить во вьюхе htmlhelper таким образом `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.tovars.Name, null, "Name")`, но тогда в поисках атрибута удаленной валидации движок лезет во внешний класс `Datas`. То есть замкнутый круг получается, переименовать невозможно, а когда насильно вводишь имя атрибута для поля ввода, то движек лезет непонятно куда. Что делать в такой ситуации ?? Вот моя Вью

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Datas
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        { 
        @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.tovars.Name)<br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.tovars.Name)<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.tovars.Cost)<br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.tovars.Cost)<br />
            <input type="submit", value="Click" />
        }
        <br />
        @if(Model != null)
        { 
        @Model.Name<br />
        @Model.Id<br />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`BindAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public JsonResult Test([Bind(Prefix="tovars")]string name)
{
    return Json(name.Length > 5, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

тогда биндер достанет значение из `tovars.name`.